# dplyr way to tabulate (summarise) several variables that share the same "levels"

Tags: r, dplyr

What is the `dplyr` way to tabulate several variables that share the same "levels" to produce the following output?

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("sometimes", "sometimes", "rarely", "never", "often",
                        "often"),
                 v2 = c("often", "sometimes", "rarely", "never", "rarely",
                        "often"))

tab <- data.frame(cbind(table(df$v1), table(df$v2)))
names(tab) <- names(df) 
tab

#          v1 v2
#never      1  1
#often      2  2
#rarely     1  2
#sometimes  2  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this approach:

```
> df %>% 
    gather(var) %>% 
    group_by(var) %>% 
    count(value) %>% 
    spread(var, n)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  value        v1    v2
  <chr>     <int> <int>
1 never         1     1
2 often         2     2
3 rarely        1     2
4 sometimes     2     1
```

As pointed out by @Frank you can go straight without `group_by`, you can count by group just using `count()`, as follows:

```
  df %>% 
  gather %>% 
  count(key,value) %>% 
  spread(key, n)
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to convert the data to "long" format, which will make easier to simply count the occurrences of your labels, then `spread` them into the desired format.

```
df.count <- df %>% 
  gather(variable, value) %>% 
  group_by(variable, value) %>% 
  count %>% 
  spread(variable, n)

  value        v1    v2
  <chr>     <int> <int>
1 never         1     1
2 often         2     2
3 rarely        1     2
4 sometimes     2     1
```

Of course, `dplyr` isn't strictly necessary:

```
df2 <- sapply(df, table)
```

This produces a named matrix, as opposed to a data frame:

```
          v1 v2
never      1  1
often      2  2
rarely     1  2
sometimes  2  1
```

And with a little more work you can turn it into a data frame:

```
df2 <- sapply(df, table) %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = 'level')
```